# Custom Title value is not getting displayed in TFS Work Item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

Sorry for confusing you with the terms. I may not be explaining correctly.

I have created a new field called Request Title (refname:SAM.OI.Requesttitle) and my Work Item Type name is Request Details.

Note: Not using refname System.Title.

Please see below screen shot. for my custom WIT.. Entered Test Request Title is not displayed next to the New Request Details 3*:... if you see for default Task WIT entered Task Title is displayed next to New Task 2*: Task Title.

Help me on how to fix to show the Request title Next to Request Details.

[image]

Comment: Please share the custom WIT XML

Answer (score 1):

Added a Rule to Title Field Definition to Copy the Request title value to Title. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to show the Request title Next to Request Details. Only the default Title can be shown there.

You could use the default Title field and add label `Request Title` to it, in this way, you will get the behavior you want:

[image]

Comment: Added a Rule to Title Field Definition to Copy the Request title value to Title. It is working as expected.